# jqGrid add additional parameters in postData.filters.rules[]

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I use jQuery UI Autocomplete.
I get data from server Object:

```
{
    value:"Aspirin"
    data:"678,677,676"
}
```

This value is inserted in html input

```
"Aspirin"
```

data I plan to put in hidden html element
and we have the following:

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"prep","op":"cn","data":"Aspirin"}]}
```

I need

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"prep","op":"cn","data":"Aspirin","id":"678,677,676"}]}
```

tell me how do I do
Thank!

Add information

when I select from the list ui.autocomplete I get the id and value.
I need these two parameters are saved for the current column and do the same for the other columns

then add the id in

```
filters:"{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"prep","op":"cn","data":"АСПИРИН"},{"field":"Dozirovka","op":"cn","data":"100"},{"field":"CountryName","op":"cn","data":"Германия"}]}"
```

here is an example

```
filters:"{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"prep","op":"cn","data":"АСПИРИН","id":"678,677,676"},{"field":"Dozirovka","op":"cn","data":"100","id":"1968456"},{"field":"CountryName","op":"cn","data":"Германия","id":"59"}]}"
```

P.S. Олег вы случайно русский не знаете?)

Comment: Sorry, but you should more clear formulate what you do, which data you use and what filter you need to use. The information about "Object" returned from the server is absolutely unclear in context of usage in jqGrid. Which exact **value** have `'"id"`? (`"id":"678,677,676"` or `"id":"678677676"`). What rule you need to implement? For example `(prep contains "Aspirin") AND (id equal to "678677676")`

Comment: I will just add ID to {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"prep","op":"cn","data":"Aspirin","id":"678,677,676"}]}

Comment: Я, конечно, знаю русский язык, но его не знают многие, кто читает stackoverflow. You have to post the code which explain more clear what you do. The format of `filters` will be used in many places of the code of jqGrid. If you use `datatype: "local"` or `loadonce: true` then any non-standard fields like `id` will be just ignored. I have to guess what you do, but I suppose that **the `id` value along identifies your data**. So the correct `rules` items of `filters` should contain ``"data":"678,677,676"`` instead of `"data":"АСПИРИН","id":"678,677,676"` and so on. You use  wrong `searchoptions`.